# Writing XML Nodes in QtXML (QDomElement)

Tags: c++, xml, qt4, qtxml

I would like to write Nodes like

```
<name>Peter</name>
```

(with start and end tag) into a QDomDocument.

When I create QDomElements and append them as child to a parent element:

```
QDomElement node = doc.createElement("node");
parent.appendChild(node);
```

They are added as

```
<node/>
```

to the parent element. The parent automatically gets a start and end tag so the file would look like this:

```
<parent>
    <node/>
</parent>
```

But how do I add a value to my node so that it looks like I want it (with value between start and end tag). Adding a new QDomElement as child to node it would just look like . Adding attribute would show up like ?

Would be great if anyone could help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a text node using DOM Document, and add it to your newly created element as a child:

```
QDomElement node = doc.createElement("name");
parent.appendChild(node);
// Now, add a text element to your node
node.appendChild( doc.createTextNode( "Peter"));
```

Comment: Thank you! This works fine... I just didn't think this was the easiest way to it like this, because xml-tags are written that way in so many files so I thought there would be an easier way... thank you!

Comment: any idea how to add more than one child eg lots of node tags all under parent

Comment: use the QDomElement::appendChild method to add as many child nodes as you like.