# How to add to an XML file structured like this in Qt?

Tags: xml, qt, qxmlstreamreader

How can I write this to an xml file using qt?

```
 <model>
  <column loop="true">`enter code here`
    <item2  color="#4d6862"  />
    <item2  color="#ff0000ff" />
    <item2  color="#ff00ff00" />
    <item2 color="#ff00ffff" />
    <item2 color="#ffff0000" />
    <item2 color="#ffff00ff" />
    <item2  color="#ffffff00" />
    <item2 color="#4d6862" />
  </column>
</model>
```

This looks promising ( [Writing XML Nodes in QtXML (QDomElement)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934630/writing-xml-nodes-in-qtxml-qdomelement) ) but it doesn't mention attributes.

Comment: `element.setAttribute(QLatin1String("loop"), QLatin1String("true"));` if the question is just about attributes. Otherwise, be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `QXmlStreamWriter`: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qxmlstreamwriter.html

```
QXmlStreamWriter writer (&file);    // a QFile object, must be open for writing
writer.setAutoFormatting(true);
writer.writeStartDocument("1.0");
writer.writeStartElement ("model");
writer.writeStartElement ("column");
    writer.writeAttribute ("loop", "true");

    writer.writeStartElement ("item2");
    writer.writeAttribute ("color", "#4d6862");
    writer.writeEndElement ();
    // write all other items

writer.writeEndDocument();   // this will close all open tags
```

Comment: Look good. Thanks. I'm going to say it is answered as I won't be able to test for a couple days and unfortunately myopenID is closing down Feb 1st and I won't be able to log in again to do it properly.